# Data area data structure data type

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am having trouble around understanding why a data area data structure

such as the one defined below fails to compile if the data area is declared to be of Decimal type of length 7.

```
D LstDat         UDS                  DTAARA('SP002DTA') 
D LastRun                        7  0
```

This seems to work only if the data area is declared to be type *char as below:

```
CRTDTAARA DTAARA(&LIB/SP002DTA) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(7) +   
  TEXT('DATA AREA FOR TRACKING SP002R RUN DATE')
```

The char value in the Data area is pulled inside the data structure without any issue as a number which also I dont understand.

Comment: Don't do this.   crtdtaara as character then use it as numeric everywhere else.

Comment: Then how to proceed about this? SO is it the case that data area data structures are meant to be used only for Character values?

Comment: Dtaara 7,0.  So it matches what it's intended use is.

Comment: So i guess you are asking me to declare the DATA AREA as a numeric . Then please can you write a clear piece of code showing how to declare the DS in the RPG?

Comment: Consider keeping the types aligned.

Comment: "Length" of a *DEC data area refers to number of digits and doesn't match up with the number of bytes. A 7-digit *DEC only covers 4 bytes. But your DS subfield is declared as a 7-byte ZONED decimal (not PACKED decimal). So your declaration data type (and therefore byte-length) doesn't match the external *DEC data area. Try declaring `LastRun` as 'P'acked to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Data structures are always characters...

Rather, the structure itself is simply a collection of bytes.  Since RPG doesn't have a byte type, character is the closest we can get.  Even if all the subfields are numeric, the entire structure would be seen as character.

Since you're tying the structure to the data area, it expects a character data area.

If you have a numeric data area,  simply use a stand a lone variable...

`D LastRun          S             7  0  DTAARA('SP002DTA')`

Comment: Data areas are always characters? What does that mean? To an RPG program you mean? Also declaring as above requires fixed calculation specs to access and modify the value i guess?

Comment: Sorry misread that. Data structures are always characters? What does that mean ?

Comment: If you declare a data structure, and use the data structure name to access it, it is treated as character data. The fields inside can be any type.

Comment: But using a stand alone variable would require fixed length C specs right? Does the method I use look to be a correct one?

Comment: no, `dcl-s lastrun packed(7,0) dtaara('SP002DTA');`

Comment: About using calculation specs to access and modify the value ... yes, you have to use the IN *LOCK and OUT opcodes. The automatic processing done for U-DS data areas is only available for character data areas.

Comment: Thanks Barbara. So, is it advisable to have a character data area value to be retrieved into a numeric data structure sub field? I have done so and works perfectly as required